# spring <sws:interceptors> to annotation based configuration

Tags: xml, spring, soap, configuration, spring-ws

im trying to migrate my soap service from xml configuration files to configuration classes but i have a problem with security interceptors.

i have the following:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="namespace1">
        <ref bean="myXwsSecurityInterceptor"/>
    </sws:payloadRoot>
</sws:interceptors>
```

in my configuration class im registering interceptor by extending WsConfigurerAdapter and overriding addInterceptors:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(myXwsSecurityInterceptor);
    }
}
```

but in this way i dont specify any payload namespaceUri, which means it intercepts every request and i dont want that since i have different soap services in my app.

i couldnt find anywhere a solution.

can anybody help please?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any answer either, but I found solution. You have to add smart interceptor to your context. Smart interceptors contain method shouldIntercept. I found out that method addInterceptor adds only normal interceptors which are applicable in whole context.

You don't even need to extend WsConfigurerAdapter to add smart interceptor, you just need to add new bean to context. Here's what I've done:

```
        @Bean
public SmartEndpointInterceptor addSmartEndpointInterceptor()
{
    try
    {
        //init myXwsSecurityInterceptor

        PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor smartInterceptor = 
            new PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor(myXwsSecurityInterceptor, "namespace1", null);

        return smartInterceptor;
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {

    }
    return null;
}
```

PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor has same attributes as   (namespace and localName) - you specify namespace and localname for which the delegated interceptor (myXwsSecurityInterceptor) should be called.